# Is $P(X < x | Y + Z = 1) = P(X < x | Y = 1) + P(X < x | Z = 1)$ when Y,Z are 0 or 1

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to solve this conditional probability and was wondering if the right side was equivalent. Y and Z are non-negative integers

I don't really see any reason this shouldn't be true?

Thanks

edit: looking at it again.. maybe I need to include the other of Y,Z equaling 0 in the 2 conditions?

Comment: This is rarely true.  Most of the time, you cannot do anything like this step.

Comment: why can't you? i can't think of any counterexamples..

Comment: You need to specify Y and Z can only assume values of $0$ or $1$.

Comment: The right hand sum can exceed $1$ and presumably will do for large enough $x$: it will approach $2$ as $x$ increases.  The left hand expression is a conditional probability and so can never exceed $1$.

Comment: What would be true (with $Y$ and $Z$ each non-nengative integer random variables) is that $P(X < x , Y + Z = 1) = P(X < x,  Y = 1, Z=0) + P(X < x , Y=0, Z = 1)$ but these are joint probabilities not conditional probabilities and avoid the possibility of $X < x , Y=1, Z = 1$ which your type of expression might count twice instead of not at all

Answer (score 0):

First note that if $P(Y=0,Z=1), P(Y=1,Z=0) > 0$ and $X$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$, then either of your equations becomes $P(X < x) = 2P(X < x)$.  That is, it's only true in this case if $P(X < x) = 0$.  This is far from being necessarily true.

[**Note**: This counterexample also covers your original question.]

---

For any three events $A,B,C$ such that $B \cap C = \emptyset$,
$$P(A\mid B \cup C) = \frac{P(B)P(A\mid B)+P(C)P(A\mid C)}{P(B)+P(C)}$$

For this to be equal to $P(A\mid B) + P(A \mid C)$, we'd need
$$P(C)P(A \mid B) + P(B)P(A \mid C) = 0$$

---

In your context, this becomes
$$P(X<x\mid Y+Z=1)=\frac{P(Y=0,Z=1)P(X<x\mid Y=0,Z=1)+P(Y=1,Z=0)P(X<x\mid Y=1,Z=0)}{P(Y+Z=1)}$$
and this would equal $P(X<x\mid Y=0,Z=1)+P(X<x\mid Y=1,Z=0)$ if and only if $$P(Y=1,Z=0)P(X<x\mid Y=0,Z=1)+P(Y=0,Z=1)P(X<x\mid Y=1,Z=0) = 0$$

If we assume $P(Y=1, Z=0), P(Y=0,Z=1) > 0$, as we did at the top of this answer, then this implies $$P(X < x \mid Y=0,Z=1) = P(X < x \mid Y=1,Z=0) = 0,$$ so that $$P(X < x \mid Y+Z=1) = 0,$$ which shows that, even in the more general scenario, the type of equation you're asking about is rarely true.